# Function Occasionally Returns None but If I Print the Return it seems fine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an application that's pulling json data from a web interface.

Most of the time the data is there but on occaasion, it's not or it returns the same thing multiple times.

I've stripped away the new lines and selected the first, assigning that to a variable. When I print my function in a loop it still prints some "None".

If I change my return to a 'print' within my function it appears to only print valid data so I'm confused as to how I still get a 'none' retern.

The function

```
def getTest():
    for o in getData():
        if 'system' in o:
            currentValue = o['tag']
            try:
                stripValue = currentValue.splitlines()[0] # grab first line and drop the rest
                print(stripValue)
            except:
                pass
```

The output

```
Talkgroup ID 54638 [0xd56e]
Talkgroup ID 54638 [0xd56e]
Talkgroup ID 54638 [0xd56e]
Talkgroup ID 54638 [0xd56e]
Talkgroup ID 54638 [0xd56e]
Talkgroup ID 54638 [0xd56e]
Talkgroup ID 54638 [0xd56e]
```

The code with 'return'

```
def getTest():
    for o in getData():
        if 'system' in o:
            currentValue = o['tag']
            try:
                stripValue = currentValue.splitlines()[0] # grab first line and drop the rest
                return(stripValue)
            except:
                pass
```

The output of above function

```
Talkgroup ID 13570 [0x3502]
None
Talkgroup ID 13570 [0x3502]
Talkgroup ID 13570 [0x3502]
Talkgroup ID 13570 [0x3502]
None
Talkgroup ID 13570 [0x3502]
```

Below is the getData function

```
def getData(debug=False):
    debug == False
    data = [{'command': 'update', 'data': 0}]
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    r = requests.post("http://pi25.local", data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    if debug == True:
        print(r.status_code, r.reason)
    data = r.json()
    return data
```

Below is the output of 'data'

Note that this changes and sometimes not all variables have values every time you query.

```
[{'nac': 835, 'wacn': 781824, 'tgid': None, 'tdma': None, 'json_type': 'change_freq', 'system': 'P25 SYSTEM', 'sysid': 840, 'tag': '', 'offset': 0, 'stream_url': '', 'freq': 855862500, 'center_frequency': None, 'fine_tune': 0.0}, {'nac': 835, '835': {'rxchan': 855862500, 'txchan': 810862500, 'frequency_data': {'854887500': {'last_activity': '   11.8', 'tgids': [13570, None], 'counter': 1577}, '855787500': {'last_activity': '    5.0', 'tgids': [27672, None], 'counter': 1515}, '855412500': {'last_activity': '    1.0', 'tgids': [13570, None], 'counter': 1729}, '854462500': {'last_activity': '   26.9', 'tgids': [6531, None], 'counter': 1646}, '854437500': {'last_activity': '   34.3', 'tgids': [27550, None], 'counter': 1448}, '854987500': {'last_activity': '   14.4', 'tgids': [54638, None], 'counter': 1706}, '855462500': {'last_activity': '   13.4', 'tgids': [27554, None], 'counter': 1729}, '852575000': {'last_activity': '   14.6', 'tgids': [27500, None], 'counter': 1963}, '856212500': {'last_activity': '   25.8', 'tgids': [54768, None], 'counter': 1510}, '856237500': {'last_activity': '   31.6', 'tgids': [54768, None], 'counter': 1506}, '855937500': {'last_activity': '   28.5', 'tgids': [27617, None], 'counter': 1774}, '854662500': {'last_activity': '    0.4', 'tgids': [54768, None], 'counter': 1547}}, 'tsbks': 84694, 'wacn': 781824, 'frequencies': {'854887500': 'voice frequency 854.887500 tgid(s) 13570 None 11.8s ago count 1577', '855787500': 'voice frequency 855.787500 tgid(s) 27672 None  5.0s ago count 1515', '855412500': 'voice frequency 855.412500 tgid(s) 13570 None  1.0s ago count 1729', '854462500': 'voice frequency 854.462500 tgid(s) 6531 None 26.9s ago count 1646', '854437500': 'voice frequency 854.437500 tgid(s) 27550 None 34.3s ago count 1448', '854987500': 'voice frequency 854.987500 tgid(s) 54638 None 14.4s ago count 1706', '855462500': 'voice frequency 855.462500 tgid(s) 27554 None 13.4s ago count 1729', '852575000': 'voice frequency 852.575000 tgid(s) 27500 None 14.6s ago count 1963', '856212500': 'voice frequency 856.212500 tgid(s) 54768 None 25.8s ago count 1510', '856237500': 'voice frequency 856.237500 tgid(s) 54768 None 31.6s ago count 1506', '855937500': 'voice frequency 855.937500 tgid(s) 27617 None 28.5s ago count 1774', '854662500': 'voice frequency 854.662500 tgid(s) 54768 None  0.4s ago count 1547'}, 'stid': 3, 'rfid': 2, 'last_tsbk': 1558581997.944967, 'adjacent_data': {'774781250': {'table': 1, 'stid': 1, 'rfid': 2, 'uplink': 804781250}, '773556250': {'table': 1, 'stid': 8, 'rfid': 2, 'uplink': 803556250}, '856037500': {'table': 0, 'stid': 10, 'rfid': 2, 'uplink': 811037500}, '771181250': {'table': 1, 'stid': 9, 'rfid': 2, 'uplink': 801181250}}, 'sysid': 840, 'syid': 840, 'secondary': [860762500, 860812500, 860862500]}, 'encrypted': 0, 'json_type': 'trunk_update', 'srcaddr': 0, 'grpaddr': 13570}, {'fine_tune': 0.0, 'files': [], 'json_type': 'rx_update', 'error': 341}]
```

I've found a way to do this without iterating but I still get this random None

```
def test():
    try:
        data = [{'command': 'update', 'data': 0}]
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        r = requests.post("http://pi25.local", data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
        data = r.json()
        return data[0]['tag']
    except:
        pass

while True:
    print(test())
```

Comment: You did not post the content of getData, but my assumption would be that it returns an empty list and then getTest will return the implicite None at the end of the method

Comment: The list itself may not be empty but the selection 'tag' sometimes is.
I'm not sure how to catch this before the return.

I've tried things like 

    if currentValue == None:

and so on but it never catches it.

I'll edit with more detail

Comment: If your 'tag' is empty it will raise Exception when calling splitlines() which you will catch ```(except: pass)```. It will keep iterating and never reach the return. At the end of your method it returns an implicite None. Which I would assume is the printed value

Comment: I've added a new method I found to pull my data from this but I still run into none the same way I did before

Comment: In your test method. Instead of pass return 'Caught Exception', you will understand the issue more.